# Handle Select Option in React giving me empty string first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am very new to reactjs . I need handle the select option in my form . And set ne useStae correspond to select option and store the value of option on change event. But the problem is that when I select the first time any option then it gives me an empty string.

This is code

```
const [gender,setGender] = useState("")

 const genderHandle = (e) =>{
        setGender(e.target.value)
        console.log(gender)
    }
  <select onChange={genderHandle}> 
      <option selected disabled>What is your gender?</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
      <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
      <option value="Anther Gender">Another Gender</option>
   </select> 


output ""
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You can't log right after setting state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referencing the output of your `console.log`.

The reason it is displaying the previous state is because the setState method is asynchronous, meaning your state has not been updated by the time your `console.log` is called.

theres many different ways this can be resolved, however the simplest may be moving the `console.log` outside of `genderHandle`

```
const [gender,setGender] = useState("");
console.log(gender);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [react docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value):

> Calling the `set` function does not change state in the running code
> ... states behaves like a snapshot. Updating state requests another render with the new state value, but does not affect the count JavaScript variable in your already-running event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The state will be set correctly, the only issue is the logging part. `useState()` is asynchronous so `console.log()` will be triggered before it even sets the new state. That's why you will always see the previous state.

You can see the real current state with something like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(gender)
}, [gender])
```